# Как заполнить массив String пустыми строками?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Я хочу создать массив String, содержащий несколько пустых строк.

```
String[] array = {"", "", "", "", ""};
```

В python мы могли бы достичь этого просто с помощью этого кода `[""] * 5`
 Есть ли что-то подобное для java?

Comment: попробуй `String[5] array = {""}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`Arrays.fill(array, "")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(char[],%20char))

Answer (score 1):

Можно в одну строчку с помощью [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-):

```
String[] array = Collections.nCopies(5, "").toArray(new String[5]);
```

или с помощью [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-):

```
String[] array = IntStream.range(0, 5).mapToObj(i-> "").toArray(String[]::new);
```

По производительности оба варианта будут хуже `Arrays.fill` т.к. создаются лишние объекты (список и поток).

Еще есть метод [`ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#nullToEmpty-java.lang.String:A-), но для него нужно будет подключить библиотеку Apache Commons:

```
 String[] array = ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty(new String[5]);
```